# Action Bar Sherlock + Robolectric

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, robolectric

We use Robolectric for our test cases at work which seems to not work well Action Bar Sherlock.

Problem is that I get a `No implementations match configuration` message, because the `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` == 0 when run via robolectric.

If anyone has ideas on the best way of getting ABS working nice with Robolectric, I'd love to know. If I find out I'll post my results here, but it seems to be very hard to find information on how to make this popular toolkit and library work together.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two ways to solve this:

1. Change Robolectric's `Build.SDK_INT` value to a real value using this gross method call: `RobolectricTestRunner.setStaticValue(Build.VERSION.class, "SDK_INT", 15);`
2. Write your own ActionBarSherlock implementation that extends from one of the existing ones and annotate with `@ActionBarSherlock.Implementation(api = 0)` (don't forget to call `ActionBarSherlock.registerImplementation` as well).

Comment: Thanks, since you wrote ABS I'm going to just accept your answer before I try. Have you considered including a dummy implementation in the ABS code for this purpose?

Comment: Well, it gets a bit more complicated than that for other parts of ABS+Robolectric interaction which is why I don't include anything. XML menu loading is a spectacular failure, for example. Definitely hoping to make it easier in the future, though.

Comment: @JakeWharton Can I simulate a click on my actionbar item, like we do it using performclick for normal buttons.

Answer (score 1):

For newer version of **Robolectric 2.2** you can change the **Build.VERSION.SDK_INT** value like this:

```
Robolectric.Reflection.setFinalStaticField(Build.VERSION.class, "SDK_INT", 15);
```